Different results in table made out of view
I am trying to enrich my item table by performing UNION ALL from freshly ingested dummyitem_table to the item_table. I am working on Azure Synapse using spark - mostly spark.sql So here are my steps I do
Ingest dummyitem_table with the schema of item_table to the lake database in Synapse workspace
Create temp view out of it, where I select all available fields + creating a PK
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW v_dummyitemtable_enriched
AS
SELECT
-1 * CAST(CONCAT(dummySKUname, CompanyCode) AS BIGINT) as PK,
col1,
col2
from schema.dummyitem_table

Perform UNION ALL - v_union_item_dummy_tables between item_table and v_dummyitemtable_enriched, took all columns from item_table which are as well available in dummyitem_table
Create table enriched_item_table out of result from UNION ALL by
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema.enriched_item_table
AS 
SELECT * from v_union_item_dummy_tables

and here goes my error. When I run query
SELECT * FROM v_union_item_dummy_tables
WHERE PK IS NULL

I got expected result - 0 null's on PK, and all columns have appropriate values, however when I run
SELECT * FROM schema.enriched_item_table
WHERE PK IS NULL

which in reality is supposed to be alike v_union_item_dummy_tables - i some got null rows and weird values in tables
data
This is how schema.dummyitem_table which I ingest looks like. Its a collection of dummy items with the schema of item_table, without PK because they're not straight from the ERP system so they don't get it



PK
ItemName
Brand
CompanyCode






0999
A
101




0998
A
102




0997
C
103




after enrichment the table will look like



PK
ItemName
Brand
CompanyCode





-999
0999
A
101



-998
0998
A
102



-997
0997
C
103




item_table schema would be the same, but with PK



PK
ItemName
Brand
CompanyCode





111
0100
A
101



112
0101
A
102



113
0102
C
103




Result of
SELECT * FROM schema.enriched_item_table
WHERE PK IS NULL




PK
ItemName
Brand
CompanyCode





null
101
null
null



null
102
null
null



null
101
null
null




Looks like column values shifted, so company code is not on its place, so does other columns, but there are lots of proper rows, only those corrupted are weird like that
How can I debug that? I see no flaw in the code. I know view and underlying table is executed differently, but I can assure that there weren't any changes in item_table during development, I create schema.enriched_item_table right after v_union_item_dummy_tables and query on it, dummyitem_table and item_table have same amount of columns. I just don't get it
Any tips, thoughts? Is it SQL syntax issue, or Synapse?

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema.enriched_item_table maybe it already exists with some junk? you should drop it and recreate perhaps?

I do drop it beforehand, also please look it has not REPLACE included, I can't even do so in Synapse, so I always drop it, if it were already there it would shout that this table exists, although thanks for your reply!
@DaleK - I've provided some table snippets. Unfortunately can't provide real data, as its NDA + the table is so big column wise and row wise that idk if markdown would handle it

In fact real data is the last thing we want, assuming the sample you have provided demonstrates the issue, thats exactly what we want.

Please read [mre]
